# Are high AUTO_INCREMENT values in cron_schedule values are problem?

Tags: deadlock, mariadb

I am debugging a checkout problem, where the shipping address is not saved. This can be reproduced only some times and on production, under unclear circumstances.

Checking the logs I found

```
Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try 
  restarting transaction, query was: UPDATE `quote_address` SET ...
```

And googling I found an [post in the Magento community forums](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Magento2-Serialization-failure-1213-Deadlock-found-when-trying/td-p/91311), stating that `cron_schedule` might be involved with deadlocks.

I did a

```
mysql> select count(*) from cron_schedule;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     3778 |
+----------+
1 row in set (32.83 sec)
```

And it took very long. So I truncated the problem and seem to be not able to reproduce the problem any more at all (before in maybe 25% of the tries)

The Id column of the cron_schedule was around 14916548, so I am wondering if that is a problem for MySQL / MariaDB (5.5.5-10.0.38-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)?